# Python - Need to understand the FOR loop

Tags: python

I am little confused by this attached FOR loop. Especially the letter `p` before `for`.

Can someone one help?

*ex. not_searched is a module*
[image: not_searched is a module]

*ex. the for loop highlighted*
[image: the for loop highlighted]

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Please see [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13646/150988 "Editing of recently closed questions") and [this](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13627/150988#13632 "Why did my edit that fixed several spelling errors get rejected as superfluous? — notes on editing images").

Comment: @Scott Alright. I will keep those in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its list comprehension.
it will list all the sys path which contain the string 'not_searched'.
To Understand.

```
for p in sys.path:
      if 'not_searched' in p:
          print(p)
```

Comment: Thanks karan. If you can see my attached screenshot there is a p before "for" statement. That part I need more clarification

Comment: The official python reference is here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions and you can find other explanations with a simple search.  But in short, `[x for x in range(5)]` is saying that for each iteration of the loop, "return" the variable `x` (add to the list)

Comment: @Sivakumarj The first `p` is the last `p` (i.e. `print (p)`) in the given answer. To put it into "casual" language, `p for p in sys.path if 'not_searched' in p` is saying "Return (print) p for each item (temporarily assigned to p) in sys.path if the string `not_searched` is currently assigned to p".

Comment: thanks #Karandeepdps,#Baldrickk,#Anaksunaman. I got it now... List comprehension is the word which I was expecting. thanks again to all _/\_